# Nested SQL query with sums at different granularity levels

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to have one result set that sums metrics from a fact table. The fact table is at the most granular level (city). I'd like the result set to show the population of a given city and also the state population in a column directly next to it. The state population is derived from the sum of all the cities population. The fact table has city_id and state_id.

The result set would have the following columns

City   State   CityPopulation   StatePopulation

Comment: Post your table structure with column formats, some data examples.  Did you try anything/what have you tried?

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some ideas on the types of information you should provide.

Comment: Sounds like you just needs different clauses in the `PARTITION BY` in your window functions.

Comment: @Larnu seems that once we again we are on the same page. That is why I asked the version. :)

Comment: *Hopefully* they **aren't** on SQL Server 2005 then @SeanLange (decomissioned my last 2008 instance last year but I'm sure the syntax was introduced with 2008). Still, it surprises me how many are still on 2008 or prior.

Comment: @Larnu I agree...sadly we still have a couple 2008 instances running in production. :(

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you just need something like this.

```
select city
    , CityPopulation = count(*) over(partition by city)
    , State
    , StatePopulation = count(*) over(partition by state)
from YourTable
group by city
    , State
order by state
    , city
```